# modulus returning incorrect amount in c program when a negative number is entered

Tags: c, scanf, modulus

Can someone please help me figure out why this program gives the wrong answer for a modulus operation when a negative number is entered in this C program?

I am pretty sure what is causing the problems is the `scanf` function. The correct answer is given when positive integers are used.

The code is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int num1 = 0;
    int num2 = 0;
    int answer = 0;
    puts("enter two number to find the modulus of...");
    if (scanf("%3d %3d",&num1,&num2) != 2)
            puts("something went wrong");
    else {
            answer = (num1 % num2);
            printf("the modulus of %d and %d is: %d\n", num1, num2, answer);
    }
}
```

Comment: @JoachimPileborg looks like it answers some questions...the main point is that *negative numbers are undefined*. I am sure C can handle something this simple though; there must be some simple solution.

Comment: You would improve this question considerably if you gave some examples of the output you consider incorrect.  It seems curious to blame `scanf()` for the answer generated by the `%` operator.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin The referenced [Modulus with a negative number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645897/modulus-with-a-negative-number) asks why C "modulus" differs from Google.  The post asks why `a%b` is "the wrong answer for a modulus operation".  IMO: This borders on either side of a duplicated post.

Comment: Can someone explain to me why the current 'duplicate' ([Modulus with a negative number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645897/modulus-with-a-negative-number)) is better than [Does either ANSI C or ISO C specify what -5 % 10 should be?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609572/does-either-ansi-c-or-iso-c-specify-what-5-10-should-be)?  The current duplicate was asked later, has a far lower score, and is itself closed as a duplicate of two other questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ANSI C, the sign of the result of the modulus operator is not defined for negative inputs. You could try `div()` from the math library ([ref](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=div&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+9.1-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html)). It returns a structure with the quotient and remainder, and it works reliably for negative inputs.

Or, as Alexey Frunze kindly suggests, you could enable C99 mode. I'm too lazy to look up the standard, but a little testing (`gcc -std=c99`) suggests the sign of the result matches the sign of the left operand. So `div()` is still best if you want ANSI compatibility.

Or, you could take total control of the situation. But you have to choose what *correct* means. The following is cribbed from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).

```
int x, y, q, r; // all snippets: left-arg, right-arg, quotient, remainder
```

## truncated division

```
q = trunc( (double)x / y);
r = x - y * q;
```

## floored division (Knuth)

```
q = floor( (double)x / y);
r = x - y * q;
```

## Euclidean division

```
q = y > 0 ? floor( (double)x / y) : ceiling( (double)x / y);
r = x - y * q;
```

Comment: `%` is defined for negative integers.

Comment: @luserdroog looks like i am out of luck for negative integers. thanks all for the quick and super smart feedback.

Comment: The C standard dropped the sign "ambiguity" in 1999 (it had been allowed by the standard from 1989).

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int main()
    {

        int num1 = 0;
        int num2 = 0;
        div_t answer;
        puts("enter two number to find the modulus of...");
        if (scanf("%3d %3d",&num1,&num2) != 2)
                puts("something went wrong");
        else {
        answer = div(num1, num2);
        printf("the modulus of %d and %d is: %d\n", num1, num2,answer.rem);
        }

        return 0;
     }

Comment: @luserdroog see above just posted 3 seconds ahead of you :D

Comment: div() gives the exact same answer as before when i initially asked my question...

Comment: Alright. I added another option. But, all of this is the *correct* behavior of C. Seriously, if it deviates from your expectations, then your expectations warrant review.

Comment: using the c99 standard with gcc also gives the same answer as before when I initially asked.. in other words compiling with c99 or using the div() method and inputting a negative number will result in the mod of the positive values with a negative sign slapped on it. so -32 and 5 as the two input numbers returns -2, instead of 3. you may notice that 32 mod 5 does equal 2 though...

Comment: Maybe *I* don't understand mod as well as I thought. I would expect -32 % 5 to be -2. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) there is confusion among experts in the very definition. But take a look at my new suggestion. Take control! Make it do what you want.

Comment: @luserdroog i tried your algorithm with a small change and still obtained an incorrect answer. check out this page, it is a modulo calculator made by some stupendous badasses [link](http://www.calculatorpro.com/calculator/modulo-calculator/)

Comment: What I'm trying to tell you is there is no absolute notion of *correct/incorrect* here. It all depends on how you decide to define the division: Euclidean, Truncated, IEEE?

Comment: @luserdroog no worries - but your code for *taking control of the situation* above does not work at all even with positive numbers. :/

Answer (score 2):

After accept answer

In C, since C99, the result of `%` is *well* defined even with negative operands.  See below.

In C, `%` operator is named the "remainder"  in C and not "modulus".

To perform a Euclidean division & remainder *without* incurring truncation, range, `double` conversion problems **:

```
void Euclidean_divide_remainder(int a, int b, int *q, int *r) {
  *q = a / b;
  *r = a % b;
  if (a < 0 && *r != 0) {
    if (b < 0) { (*q)++; *r -= b; }
    else {       (*q)--; *r += b; }
  }
}

void rtest(int a, int b) {
  int eq, er;
  Euclidean_divide_remainder(a, b, &eq, &er);
  printf("f(%2d,%2d) / %2d  %% %2d  E/ %2d  E%% %2d\n", 
      a, b, a / b, a % b, eq, er);
}

void rtest4(int a, int b) {
  rtest(a, b);
  rtest(a, -b);
  rtest(-a, b);
  rtest(-a, -b);
  printf("\n");
}

int main(void) {
  rtest4(7, 3);
  return 0;
}

f( 7, 3) /  2  %  1  E/  2  E%  1
f( 7,-3) / -2  %  1  E/ -2  E%  1
f(-7, 3) / -2  % -1  E/ -3  E%  2
f(-7,-3) /  2  % -1  E/  3  E%  2
```

> The result of the / operator is the quotient from the division of the first operand by the second; the **result of the % operator is the remainder**. In both operations, if the value of the second operand is zero, the behavior is undefined. C11dr §6.5.5 5
>
> When integers are divided, the result of the / operator is the algebraic quotient with any
>   fractional part discarded. (This is often called ‘‘truncation toward zero’’.) If the quotient `a/b` is representable, the expression `(a/b)*b + a%b` shall equal `a`; otherwise, the behavior of both `a/b` and `a%b` is undefined. C11dr §6.5.5 6

** Exceptions:

The result of `a%0` is undefined.

For 2's complement, `INT_MIN % -1` and `INT_MIN E% -1`  (which mathematically should be 0) are problems.  This is caused by `INT_MIN / -1` (which mathematically should be `INT_MAX + 1`) is a problem as the answer does not fit in the `int` range..

Comment: Interesting. I have not coded C in several months or maybe it has been over a year now! 0_o I compiled your code on my machine and ran it and  obtained the same output but this example is rather confusing in my honest opinion (IMHO). I appreciate all the excitement over my c programming question though! Cool. Thanks for replying to my post guise. :D