# Why does Python's modulus operator (%) not match the Euclidean definition?

Tags: python

Euclidean definition says,

> Given two integers a and b, with b ≠ 0, there exist unique integers q and r such that a = bq + r and 0 ≤ r < |b|, where |b| denotes the absolute value of b.

Based on below observation,

```
>>> -3 % -2   # Ideally it should be (-2 * 2) + 1
-1
>>> -3 % 2    # this looks fine, (-2 * 2) + 1 
1
>>> 2 % -3    # Ideally it should be (-3 * 0) + 2
-1
```

looks like the `%` operator is running with different rules.

- [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883004/negative-numbers-modulo-in-python) was not helpful,
- [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10063546/modulo-for-negative-dividends-in-python?rq=1) gives recursive answer, because, as I do not understand how `%` works, it is difficult to understand How  `(a // b) * b + (a % b) == a` works

My question:

How do I understand the behavior of modulo operator in python? Am not aware of any other language with respect to the working of `%` operator.

Comment: to know whats going on, look at the `divmod` function. That gives you the devision and modulo of two numbers at the same time. integer division in python is always the division rounded to the next smaller integer. So -3 / -2 is 1.5 rounded to 1, with -1 left as modulo.

Comment: @jonrsharpe [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883004/negative-numbers-modulo-in-python) was not helpful, [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10063546/modulo-for-negative-dividends-in-python?rq=1) gives recursive answer, Because, As i do not understand How % works, How can i understand `(a // b) * b + (a % b) == a` works? despite this is in format of bq+r?

Comment: I'm not sure this is a duplicate: the linked questions are mostly about negative *dividends*, not negative *divisors*.  The OP seems to be already happy with the behaviour for negative dividends.

Comment: Just for the record, Python is closer to the definition you quoted than most other common programming languages.  For positive _b_, it follows this defintion, whereas e.g. C++ and Java don't when _a_ is negative.

Answer (score 5):

The behaviour of integer division and modulo operations are explained in an article of [The History of Python](http://python-history.blogspot.it/), namely: [Why Python's Integer Division Floors](http://python-history.blogspot.it/2010/08/why-pythons-integer-division-floors.html) . I'll quote the relevant parts:

> if one of the operands is negative, the result is floored, i.e.,
>   rounded away from zero (towards negative infinity):
>
> ```
> >>> -5//2
> -3
> >>> 5//-2
> -3
> ```
>
> This disturbs some people, but there is a good mathematical reason.
>   The integer division operation (`//`) and its sibling, the modulo
>   operation (`%`), go together and satisfy a nice mathematical
>   relationship (all variables are integers):
>
> `a/b = q` with remainder `r`
>
> such that
>
> `b*q + r = a` and `0 <= r < b`
>
> (assuming `a` and `b` are `>= 0`).
>
> If you want the relationship to extend for negative `a` (keeping `b`
>   positive), you have two choices: if you truncate `q` towards zero, `r`
>   will become negative, so that the invariant changes to `0 <= abs(r)`
>   otherwise, you can floor `q` towards negative infinity, and the
>   invariant remains `0 <= r < b`.
>
> In mathematical number theory, mathematicians always prefer the latter
>   choice (see e.g. Wikipedia). For Python, I made the same choice
>   because there are some interesting applications of the modulo
>   operation where the sign of a is uninteresting.
>   [...]
>   For negative b, by the way, everything just flips, and the invariant
>   becomes:
>
> ```
> 0 >= r > b.
> ```

In other words python decided to *break* the euclidean definition in certain circumstances to obtain a better behaviour *in the interesting cases*. In particular negative `a` was considered interesting while negative `b` was *not* considered as such. **This is a completely arbitrary choice, which is not shared between languages.**

Note that many common programming languages (C,C++,Java,...) do *not* satisfy the euclidean invariant, often in *more cases* than python (e.g. even when `b` is positive).
some of them don't even provide any guarantee about the sign of the remainder, leaving that detail as implementation defined.

---

As a side note: Haskell provides *both* kind of moduluses and divisions. The standard euclidean modulus and division are called `rem` and `quot`, while the floored division and "python style" modulus are called `mod` and `div`.

Comment: Note that for positive `b`, Python's behaviour *is* perfectly consistent with the Euclidean division theorem as stated in the question, regardless of the sign of `a`.  The OP's question appears to be about the behaviour for negative *divisors*, rather than the more usual question about negative *dividends*.

Comment: @MarkDickinson This is addressed in the last paragraph: "For negative `b` everything just flips and the invariant becomes `0 >= r > b`".

Comment: Yep.  But your comment about Python breaking the Euclidean definition is misleading, IMO:  it actually *agrees* with the Euclidean definition, in a situation where *many* other common languages (C99, Java, ...) don't.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Yes but allowing `r < 0` makes the euclidean invariant false, even though only in a particular case. I'll add a remark about other languages.

Comment: There's no particular canonical statement for the Euclidean algorithm for negative b, though.  Out of three elementary number theory books I just checked, two restricted the statement to positive b and arbitrary a, while the third stated the theorem in the form "... 0 >= r > b for negative b".  So allowing `r < 0` does not make the euclidean invariant false; it just doesn't agree with the *particular* choice of statement the OP made.

Comment: @MarkDickinson The OP is probably quoting the definition from wikipedia. In particular the page about [Euclidean division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division). Note that in the page they *do* take into account negative `b`s and the algorithm provided *does* maintain the invariant (`r >= 0`) in all cases.

Comment: Yep.  Like I said, there's no canonical statement.  Python *does not* break the Euclidean Algorithm definition.

Comment: @MarkDickinson I agree with you. Also from Guido's word, apparently he doesn't think it breaks the Euclidean definition, he said *"... you can floor q towards negative infinity, and the invariant remains 0 <= r < b."*