# Modulo operator reports different results with negative value

Tags: javascript, math, operator-keyword, modulo

I type this into google/wolfram alpha:

`-15 % 360`

and I get `345`.

when I do it in javascript I get `-15`

https://www.google.com/search?q=-15%20%%20360

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-15+mod+360

http://jsfiddle.net/BG3jW/

Comment: Run it for yourself and see I have tested in every environment known to man from Dolphin, Safari, Chrome, Firefox, IE, Opera

Comment: Btw, Coffeescript fixes this with the `%%` operator.

Comment: It's not "broken". It is well defined in the [ECMAScript specification](http://es5.github.io/#x11.5.3).

Comment: modulo has to satisfy a%b=a-(a/b)*b relative to integer division. Now one had to decide what is more natural for the value of (-15)/360, 0 or -1. 0 gives a negative remainder, -1 the positive remainder. JS decides for rounding towards 0 in integer division, thus giving negative remainders.

Answer (score 1):

The % ([remainder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Remainders)) operator is not "broken" in JavaScript, even though the result may be unexpected - especially with the anticipation of a stricter mathematical modulus operation.

The behavior is well-defined in ECMAScript. See [11.5.3 Applying the % Operator](http://es5.github.io/#x11.5.3):

> The % [*remainder*] operator yields the remainder of its operands from an implied division; the left operand is the dividend and the right operand is the divisor..
>
> .. the [floating-point] remainder r from a dividend n and a divisor d is defined by the mathematical relation r = n − (d * q) *where q is an integer that is negative only if n/d is negative and positive only if n/d is positive* ..

In this manner it behaves in the same way as the [remainder operator in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4403542/how-does-java-do-modulus-calculations-with-negative-numbers) or C# (for integer inputs).

There are arguments that it [should be referred to as the remainder operator](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/12/05/what-s-the-difference-remainder-vs-modulus.aspx) to avoid such confusion: ES5 does indeed implicitly refer to it as the "remainder operator", but the [Mozilla JavaScript Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Arithmetic_operators) calls it the "modulus operator".

---

See also [Modulus operation with negatives values - weird thing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43775/modulus-operation-with-negatives-values-weird-thing?rq=1), which actually views the "brokeness" from the other angle.